# I have data table with sliders in primefaces5.And horizontal bar chart.By sliding the bar in chart will move

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have data table with sliders in primefaces5.And horizontal bar chart.By moving slider then bar in chart will move. And this is working properly. Now the problem is if data table has multiple pages.How can I get the chart according to the current page.

```
     <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label, value" style="width:100%">
     <h:panelGrid columns="1" columnClasses="label, value" style="width:40%">
       <p:dataTable value="#{improvementManageBean.lazyModel}" var="entryList" varStatus="status" rows="10" paginator="true"    paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown}  {CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}  "
                        rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" style="margin-bottom:20px" id="SCS2_tbl"  widgetVar="pan2Tbl" lazy="true">


           <p:column style="width:200px">
                <h:outputText value="#{entryList.sourceName}: #{entryList.sourceType}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column style="width:200px">   
                <p:slider for="input2"  style="width:200px" id="srd2" minValue="" maxValue="454544">
                    <p:ajax event="slideEnd"   listener="#{improvementManageBean.onSlideEnd2}" update=":form:scope2Chrt,:form:panDtl"/>
                </p:slider>
            </p:column>
            <p:column style="width:80px">
                <p:inputText id="input2" value="#{entryList.co2Emission}" style="width:40px"/>
            </p:column>
    <p:ajax event="page"  listener="#{improvementManageBean.update}" />
     </p:dataTable>
</h:panelGrid>
 <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="width:60%; height:100%;" >
            <div>
                <p:barChart id="scope2Chrt" value="#{improvementManageBean.horizontalBarChartScope2}"  orientation="horizontal"
                     style="width:700px;height:900px;" animate="false" xaxisAngle="-30"
                     widgetVar="chartScp2" />
            </div>
 </h:panelGrid>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: Here, `update=":form:scope2Chrt,:form:panDtl"`. What is `:form:panDtl`?

Comment: `<p:barChart>` is displayed in sequence according to the given `<p:slider>` at the end of each slide using the `slideEnd` event. How does `<p:barChart>` stop working, when you move to a different page in `<p:dataTable>` which is already being lazily loaded? It should not give you a trouble, if the given `<p:barChart>` is given values according to the current page of `<p:dataTable>`.

Comment: Thanks Tiny    :form:panDtl  is anather grid panel.But i want per silder per bar. If i have 100 sliders in 10 pages of data table . And want 10 sliders per page having respective bar charts only(means 10 bars).